# How to extend jquery jqXHR object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Can we add additional methods to jqXHR object?
I had a app built using prototype.js which was extending the response

```
Ajax.Response.addMethods({});
```

What is the equivalent for Jquery?

I want to add few methods that are specific to my app.
For example, I want to add a method

```
getMyHeader: function(name)
{
     return this.getResponseHeader('MY-'+name);
}
```

which returns me a specific header sent by server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like jQuery specifically supports this. The jqXHR object they create is just a generic object with methods added as properties so there isn't a prototype you can modify and I don't see any jQuery methods for modifying it.

The only work-around I could see was to register a handler for a global ajax event like [`jQuery.ajaxSend()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) and add the desired methods to each specific jqXHR object in that global handler.  Then, those methods would be available later.